# ASP.NET Can't find stored procedure, but stored procedure exists

Tags: stored-procedures, database-connection, aspdotnetstorefront

I am trying to upgrade a slightly modified version of aspdotnetstorefront from 9.0.3 to 9.3.0.0. I have installed the store on my local machine (Win 7, IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2012).

When I run the site, I note 1) that there are missing product images on the home page and 2) if I click to go to a category or product I get the InvalidRequest page.

When I run Debug  on the site using Visual Studio 2012, I see the error causing the invalid request is "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspdnsf_GetMappedObject'." (I was going to post a screen grab here, but I don'e have enough reputation points.)

If I look at the Database it self, I see that the stored procedure does in fact exist. (Same here no screen as I'm not allowed.)

The above makes me suspect that my data base connection is incorrect. It is as follows:

`<add key="DBConn" value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=505916_adn_upgrade;user id=XX;password=XXXXXX;persist security info=True;packet size=4096" />`

however, I also have a 'clean' install that seems to work, it's database connection is the same with exception of the database name, user, password, which makes me think the connect ion IS correct?

I am pretty much a newbie to ALL of this stuff, so any suggests woul dbe most appreciated.

Comment: did you try that other user/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up and rebuilt the entire database - I had added the missing stored procedure only to find that there were MORE missing stored procedures. Obviously, something went wrong when the database was set up. It is working locally now.